# What is the privilege point required to edit questions

Tags: discussion

One of my friends has 1 reputation and 1 bronze badge. He has tried to increase his reputation by suggesting edits to questions and answers.

But his edits are not reviewed. Why?

Or what are the privilege minimum point(reputation) required to edit questions ?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that all of his edits are getting rejected- you will not earn any reputation for a rejected edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you gain **2K** reputation you will get privilege to Aprove, edit and reject edition on question and answers.